# Asp.net cached objects staying in memory

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, caching, garbage-collection

I have  a asp.net web forms app that uses System.Web.Caching.Cache to cache xml data from a number of web services for 2 hours.

```
  webCacheObj.Remove(dataCacheKey)
  webCacheObj.Insert(dataCacheKey, dataToCache, Nothing, DateTime.Now.AddHours(2), Nothing)
```

Every 90 minutes a Microsoft Search Server hits a particular (spider) page which calls the code to put the objects into the cache.

The issue i have is that over a period of time, the memory usage of the application grows exponentially.  Lets say that in a week, the memory usage of the application pool grows to over 1gb.

I'm using IIS7 and no application pool recycling is currently enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first stop should be [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y13wyk9.aspx). Is a relatively short man page. Learn it, love it, live it. ;-)

That said, try this:

```
Cache.Insert(dataCacheKey, dataToCache, Nothing, DateTime.Now.AddHours(2), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration)
```

p.s. whats up with `webCacheObj`? Is there a reason you are not calling the static Cache?

Comment: webCacheObj is a parameter thats passed in to a function in a seperate VB.NET dll class which adds items to the cache. (ByVal webCacheObj As Cache).

Comment: so it's just a reference to the normal cache object.

Comment: Adding Cache.NoSlidingExpiration fixed it....  Not sure why it was set to nothing.... Thanks muchly.

Comment: @GordonB, pleasure. Also, thanks for not complaining when I borked the expiration by using a timespan. fixed it in the post.